# Having Trouble Understanding a MOV Concept (Assembly Language)

Tags: assembly, move, mov

I'm trying to decipher a piece of code for my CENG class, and I've come across a few areas that I find confusing. The code is as follows ($ indicates hexadecimal):

```
C EQU $202200
ORG $201150
A DC.W 639
B DC.W -215
ORG $201200
MOVE A,R0    <---??
ADD B,R0     <---??
MOVE R0,C
```

The marked lines are what I'm having trouble deciphering. I understand that I create a variable C equal to $202200, move the starting memory, create variables A and B and give them values, then move the starting memory again. This is where I get stuck. I would under stand MOV R0, A, which would just put the value of A into the register R0, but how can you put a register into a variable? It doesn't make sense to me and Google is drawing a blank, can anyone help me understand this? Thanks.

Comment: Did they tell you the name of the processor you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

The `mov` instruction copies the *value* stored in one location (register, memory etc.) to another location. In your code snippet, it looks like it's using the convention:

```
INSTRUCTION <source>, <destination>
```

So the lines:

```
MOVE A, R0
ADD B, R0
```

Mean:

- Copy the value stored at the memory location indicated by variable `A` into the register `R0`.
- Add the value stored in the memory location indicated by variable `B` to the value in register `R0`, store the result in `R0`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, but I don't think that's the case. If that's true, then the bottom line gives me the exact same problem. MOV A, R0 and MOV R0, C. So ONE of them needs to be reversed, so again, what does it mean?

And I believe this is ARM.